# How do I rewrite GET parameters?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, get

I'm trying to rewrite $_GET parameters via .htaccess. I've tried several examples, but with no love whatsoever. Basically what I want is the following:

This url:

```
domain.com/news/message.php?item=12
```

should become:

```
domain.com/news/item/12
```

This is my current .htaccess file which only yet hides the .php extension:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the news directory you could state your condition in the rewriterule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^news/item/(.*) /news/message.php?item=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```